# How to link to third party library?

Tags: ros, third-party, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm still working on the communication between ROS electric and Promethe Neural Network simulator and I'm trying to *rosmake* a node that includes Promethe C functions. I'm using the following CMakeLists.txt :

I can rosmake witjout error but I get :

```
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< promROS_connector [SKIP] No rule to make target None
```

And no executable in bin/ . I would know if my CMakeLists is correct and what I exactly have to use to compile with third party C compiled libraries. The ~/simulateur is in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

Thanks for reading and answering.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries

#****************** INCLUDES **************************

include_directories(~/simulateur/prom_user/include)

include_directories(~/simulateur/libcomm/include)
include_directories(~/simulateur/libcomm/include/protocol/virtual)

include_directories(~/simulateur/prom_tools/include)
include_directories(~/simulateur/prom_kernel/include)
include_directories(~/simulateur/shared/include)

#*******************************************************

link_directories(~/simulateur/lib/Linux/comm)
rosbuild_add_executable(prom2ROS src/prom_to_ROS.cpp)
target_link_libraries(prom2ROS ~/simulateur/lib/Linux/comm/libcomm_debug)
```

EDIT :

After using :

```
 target_link_libraries(prom2ROS libcomm_debug)
```

the error is :

```
   Linking CXX executable ../bin/prom2ROS
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcomm_debug
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does I have to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to allow ld to find the libcomm_debug (it is now empty - libcomm_debug is a .a static library) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40154/how-to-link-to-third-party-library-?/) by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on ROS Answers with karma: 697 on 2012-07-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-30**:
Does `target_link_libraries(prom2ROS -lcomm_debug)` work? (libcomm_debug is already prebuild?)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-30**:
Also, what is: promROS_connector?  The ~/simulateur doesn't need to be in the package path as it is not a ROS package (right? otherwise you should like via export flags in the manifest)

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-30**:
@dornhege: remove the '-l' prefix, that should work. CMake expects library names in `target_link_libraries`, it is not a direct replacement for what you'd write in a linking statement for `ld`, as CMake performs dependency resolution on the listed libraries.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-30**:
Yes, that's nicer.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-30**:
target_link_libraries(prom2ROS libcomm_debug) is better in the sense that it throw an error - I'm editing the message for more details. Thanks for help.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-30**:
@Erwan R.: see my edit, I forgot to remove the `lib` prefix.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-30**:
Done, it works ! Many many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> target_link_libraries(prom2ROS ~/simulateur/lib/Linux/comm/libcomm_debug)

This is probably what isn't working for you. You've already specified the library search path with:

> link_directories(~/simulateur/lib/Linux/comm)

`target_link_libraries` now needs the individual library names you want to link, without the paths. This:

> target_link_libraries(prom2ROS comm_debug)

would probably be enough.

---

Besides that, there some things I'd do differently:

- don't use relative paths, they are dependent on the `cwd`, which is fragile (not in this case, but in general they are)
- try to use an existing `FindXXX` script (or write one, in this case for the libraries and include paths of your simulator)
- if not available / desirable / possible, try to use `find_library`, `find_path`, etc, instead of hard coding their locations

---

EDIT: Oops, forgot to remove the `lib` prefix from the library. Updated my answer above.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-30**:
If you are a bit daring, you could also build your library with cmake and then you should be able to include that directly with catkin.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-30**:
I'm gonna check for these find methods. That would be better than theses explicit paths (but the simulator is usually installed at user's root, even if it could change). May the  "~ " be also a problem ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-30**:
In that case I'd advise to use "the intended" method, whatever that is, for users to discover the library. If it is installed system-wide, as a normal package, standard include/linker paths might suffice.